# Questions on singleton design pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, singleton

I am following a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) to understand the single ton design pattern. I have few questions with respect to the approach they followed.

IN THE SECOND APPROACH Static Initialization

- it is not clear to me  why this class was declared as sealed.
  why did they mark the private instance variable( instance ) as readonly ?

Comment: There's some decent information on the Programmer Exchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/the-singleton-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class was not declared as static, but as sealed (other classes can't subclass it). It's done because the singleton implementation in question knows to instantiate only instances of this specific class.

If you subclass it: 
    `public class Child: Singleton { ... }`
the Child class will still instantiate the base class:
    `Child.Instance`
will still return instance of Singleton), which will result in confusing code.

The readonly increases code readability and prevents mistakes in future modification of the class.

Comment: my mistake, it is declared as sealed.

Comment: even though i subclass a singleton class. i cannot create an instance of the subclass because of the private constructor in singleton class.i am still not clear with your explanation your statment - "the singleton will still instantiate the base class"; which base class it will instantiate ? can you bit clear?

Comment: If you have a singleton class A that is implemented as on MSDN. And then you write class B that inherits A, then even when you call B.Instance - you'll get instance of A.
To prevent this confusion - the sealed keyword prevents inheriting the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

Per one of the following sentences:

> In addition, the variable is marked readonly, which means that it can
>   be assigned only during static initialization (which is shown here) or
>   in a class constructor.

No, you strictly wouldn't *need* this - but it would cause significant additional confusion and complexity if you allow a singleton to be initialized more than once.

The inner-most `Instance` is a property, not a class - and making it static allows for easy access without having to first create an instance of the `Instance` class, which would be unnecessary and not really provide any benefit.

Comment: As i am initializing the instance at the time of declaration itself. i don't think marking this variable readonly makes any sense. this is just my understanding.

Comment: @kumar - Yes, you are initializing at at the time of declaration, but without making it read-only, there would be nothing besides convention to prevent it from being modified later - which leads back to my above points - as well as those explained in the other answers here.